# How do I make a multiplicative table for $\mathbb Z_2[x]/{(x^3+1)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I honestly don't know how to do this, can someone explain how, I'll type out what i have in my notebook, and would very much appreciate any help on enlightening the matter.

$p(x)=x^3+1 \implies $ p(x) is reducible on $mathbb Z_2$, and $\implies\mathbb Z_2[x]/{(x^3+1)}$ is a field (I understand this)

Then they make this table which i have no clue how is gotten, and would love it if someone could explain:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $.$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x^2$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x+x^2$

$\  \ 1\ \ \ \ \ $.$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x^2$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x+x^2$

$\  \ x\ \ \ \ \ $.$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ x$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ x^2$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x+x^2$

$\   x^2\ \ \ \ \ $.$\ \ \ \ \ \ x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   1$$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x+x^2$

$1+x\ $.$\ \ \ \ \ 1+x$$\ \ \   x+x^2$$ \ \  1+x^2$ $\ \  1+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0$

$1+x^2 $.$\ \ \ 1+x^2$$\ \ \  1+x$$ \ \ \   x+x^2$ $\ \  x+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x $$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1+x^2$$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0$

.... I goes on to column $x^2+x+1$ but its tiring to make this..

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$?

Comment: I do exactly mean so

Comment: Formatting advice: use `\begin{matrix} ... \end{matrix}` to save yourself a headache. Have a look at this nice [reference page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: thanks a bunch, ill remember this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rows/columns are the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$ Since it is finite, you only need worry about a finite number of rows/columns ($1$, $x$, ..., $1+x+x^2$).

To fill in the table, multiply the elements as usual (i.e., polynomial multiplication), but afterwards you must simplify the result using the fact that $1+1=0$ (because the coefficients are elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$) and $x^3+1=0\implies x^3=-1$ (because you are modding out $x^3+1$).

If you're familiar with [multiplication tables for groups](http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/aaol/grouptables1.html), this is a similar idea.

---

Some examples:

$$(x+x^2)\cdot(1+x) = x + \color{red}{2x^2} + \color{green}{x^3} = x + \color{red}{0} \color{green}{- 1} = x+\color{green}{1}$$

$$(1+x^2)\cdot(1+x+x^2) = x^3 (1+x) + \color{red}{2x^2} + x + 1 = \color{red}{0}+\color{green}{(x^3 + 1)}(1+x) = \color{green}{0}(1+x)=0$$

Comment: Thanks, I was skimming too quickly. Answer updated.

Comment: could you explain how $1,x .., 1+x+x^2$ are the elements of $ \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+1)$? And i'll be completely satisfied .

Comment: The elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$ are the polynomials with coefficients in $\{0,1\}$. By modding out $x^3+1$, we essentially enforce the highest degree to be 2 (since $x^3$ becomes "$1$ in disguise"). Then explicitly writing out all combinations of polynomials of degree 0,1,2 with coefficients in $\{0,1\}$ gets you the list of all elements.

Comment: For example if I have $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^3+x)$ , i would mod out from $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ $x^3+x$ , how does this modding out work?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/(2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ is "integers mod 2" because $2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Similarly, $5=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Now when you mod out $x^3+x$, you are adding another "rule" that says $x^3+x=0$, and you would use this computationally (in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$) as $x^3=-x=4x$ (i.e., if you have a polynomial with degree $\geq 3$, factor out the $x^3$ term wherever it appears and rewrite as $4x$).